# How do I display multiple fields when using distinct count?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to get a count of total different first and last names with the same email address, and I'm not sure where to go from here. Field1 and Field2 are in the same table.

My output should have the concatenated `field`, `field 1`, `field2`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(first_name,last_name)))
   FROM `datalake.core.profile_snapshot` 
   WHERE classic_country = 'US' and
       email.personal = 'example@provider.net'
   LIMIT 1000
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe `SELECT emailaddress, COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(first_name, last_name) FROM... WHERE... GROUP BY emailaddress`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
first_name
,last_name
,email_address
,count(1) as number
FROM datalake.core.profile_snapshot
GROUP BY 
first_name
,last_name
,email_address
```

If you want to reduce the result set to a particular email address then just add a where clause to do so.

I've used `email_address` instead of `email.personal`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
What if I wanted to only list those with number (count) great than 100?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! At the bottom of the query add the line "Having count (1) > 100"

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT for SQL is generally limiting the number of rows returned, not for filtering. Need to use `HAVING` to filter on your aggregate

### Email with 1000+ Distinct Names

```
SELECT email
    /*Put random pipe character "|" in between first and last name so don't get names that concatenate to same value
    Such as Jane Doe and Jan Edoe. Not a realistic example but concatenation could result in same "value" without a separator*/
    ,DistinctNames = COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(first_name,'|',last_name))
FROM datalake.core.profile_snapshot
WHERE classic_country = 'US'
AND email.personal = 'example@provider.net' /*Can comment this out if you want to see all email with 1000+ distinct names*/
GROUP BY email
/*HAVING clause = WHERE clause for aggregates*/
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(first_name,'|',last_name)) > 1000 /*1000 distinct names for each email*/
```